# add div to all parser results using str_replace

Tags: php, parsing, str-replace, simple-html-dom

I'm using this string to get what's needed:

```
echo "<div id=\"lot\">".$table->children(2)->children(0)->plaintext."</div>";
```

And I get the result: 01 02 03 04 05 06 10 15 17 27 31 etc.

What I need is to add `<div id=\"new\"></div>` to each number.

`<div id=\"new\">01</div> <div id=\"new\">02</div>` etc etc.

I tried to use the code below but it doesn't work

```
 $table = $box_rezult->find("table.last-d", 0);
        $results = $table->children(2)->children(0)->plaintext;
        $string = $results;
        $var1 = str_replace(" ", "<div id=\"new\"> </div>", $string);
        echo $var1;
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Thanks to everyone!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[explode()](http://php.net/explode) the string to an array, then [implode()](http://php.net/implode) it:

```
echo '<div class="new">' . implode('</div><div class="new">', explode(' ', $string)) . '</div>';
```

I've changed `id` to `class` as `id's` must be unique.

#### [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/W6aJ7j)

Answer (score 0):

For your use case you need to flip tags to get a separator and pre- and append one more:

```
$var1 = "<div id=\"new\">" . str_replace(" ", "</div> <div id=\"new\">", $string) . "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$string` contains all the numbers you want,
you can explode it and put each element you want to have in tags for each number and then apply it to string, using a loop (or `implode`, as suggested):

```
$numbers = explode(" ", $string);
$var1 = ""; 
foreach($numbers as $number){
  $var1 .= "<div id=\"new\">".$number."</div>";
}
```

Also, please take into consideration about [id attribute uniqueness](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really). Use `class` attribute instead.

Comment: thanks but now the result is `<div id="new">01 02 03 04</div>;`

Comment: You are welcome. Consider voting up the question, but also looking on all your answers and choosing the best of those as a thank you to those who helped.